# How To deserialize an Atom feed using DataContracts

Tags: c#, xml, datacontractserializer, datacontract, atom-feed

I am trying to cast an XML that use Atom feed with a Datacontract class and I am failing....

my code is the following one:

```
Content.ReadAsAsync<ArticleDTOs>()

      [Serializable]
 [DataContract(Namespace = "urn:schemas-something:some", Name = "document")]
    public class ArticleDTOs  
    {

        [DataMember(Name = "entry")]
        public entry entry { get; set; }

        }

    [Serializable]
    [DataContract(Namespace ="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")]
    public class entry
    {
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

     }
}
```

I have the feeling that the problem is related to the namespace declaration in the

datacontract.... how I am supposed to set the Namespace to read correctly the XML Namespace???

this is the XML that I have to deserialize

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<document id="m.fy7c2fsvzxtv" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns="urn:schemas-something:some">

<atom:entry><atom:id>m.fy7c2fsvzxtv</atom:id><atom:title>test title</atom:title><atom:published>2013-07-08T17:21:06.4035574+01:00</atom:published><atom:updated>2013-07-08T17:21:06.4050577+01:00</atom:updated><subheadline>test sub headline</subheadline><standfirst>desc</standfirst><keywords>keywords</keywords>

<atom:content>body with Encoding </atom:content></atom:entry></document>
```

Comment: `atom:id` is also in the Atom namespace. Do you need to specify this in your class? Do you get a specific error?

Comment: No exception is thrown but the property with different namespace is set as null, changing the namespace it works... as far as I have understood, DataContractSerializer does not support multiple namespace... I have decided to use XmlSerializer worst performance but more flexibility and wider syntax supported...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, or I otherwise I would have asked for clarification in the comments...

As per your example XML that you have to deserialize, the double quotes (`"`) are escaped in the version, encoding and id attributes. As shown, this is not valid XML.

Is the XML an output of your own program? If so, find where it is escaping the characters and prevent it from doing so when writing the output.

If that is the file you have to work with, then I suggest removing all backslashes escaping a double quote:

```
// We have to escape the backslash and the quote both, with a backslash
xmlString.Replace("\\\#","\#");
```

Perhaps that solves your problem?

Lastly, you only mention that your code is 'failing', and fail to provide any kind of exception or error message... Please provide more details as to how your code is failing if the above solution does not work for you.

Comment: Hi Adam, the problem is not related with the XML, the "\" where coming from a copy and paste... when I say it fails to deserealize, it means that it is not able to MAP the entry object on the ArticleDTO class.... I have done quite a lot of experiments and it seems that the issue is related to the namespace....